# Apply filters to Google Analytics query URI in Power BI

Tags: google-analytics, powerbi

I'm querying google analytics from power bi for use with dashboarding and all that. I'm trying to look at page views for a specific page, but power bi likes to bring in all the data first THEN filter. I know the google analytics query URI can be written to filter on just the page I'm interested in, though. I'm wondering: how do I convert my power bi query to make use of that filter?

The power bi query I'm using looks like this:

```
let
    Source = GoogleAnalytics.Accounts(),
    #"###" = Source{[Id="###"]}[Data],
    #"UA-###-10" = #"###"{[Id="UA-###-10"]}[Data],
    #"#####" = #"UA-###-10"{[Id="#####"]}[Data],
    #"Added Items" = Cube.Transform(#"#####",
        {
            {Cube.AddAndExpandDimensionColumn, "ga:pagePath", {"ga:pagePath"}, {"Page"}},
            {Cube.AddMeasureColumn, "Pageviews", "ga:pageviews"}
        })
in
    #"Added Items"
```

But this gives me *all* pages, I only want a specific one.

The google analytics URI query looks like:

https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?ids=ga%3A###&start-date=30daysAgo&end-date=yesterday&metrics=ga%3Apageviews&dimensions=ga%3ApagePath&sort=-ga%3Apageviews&filters=ga%3ApagePath%3D%40%2Fprofile%2Faccount

This gives me the correct result since it's doing the filtering for the site that I want at the query level.

Any ideas on how to get the `&filters=...` part at the end of the URI to work correctly in the power bi query?

Answer (score 1):

You can just make use of Power BI's filter and no need to worry that much. Simply select the page you want to filter in the Query Editor.

[image: filter]

It is because Power BI will try to combine and simplify the steps in the query into an API request before sending it to Google Analytics. You can verify it with [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) when refreshing the data in Power BI:

[image: api request]

Of course you can write your own code in the Advanced Editor, but it's essentially the same as above:

```
let
    Source = GoogleAnalytics.Accounts(),
    #"###" = Source{[Id="###"]}[Data],
    #"UA-###-10" = #"###"{[Id="UA-###-10"]}[Data],
    #"#####" = #"UA-###-10"{[Id="#####"]}[Data],
    #"Added Items" = Cube.Transform(#"#####",
        {
            {Cube.AddAndExpandDimensionColumn, "ga:pagePath", {"ga:pagePath"}, {"Page"}},
            {Cube.AddMeasureColumn, "Pageviews", "ga:pageviews"}
        }),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Added Items", each ([Page] = "/Admin/?newCompany=true"))
in
    #"Filtered Rows"
```

Comment: Hi @ai52487963 this help solving the issue after all? If so, you can [accept this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/313506) to positively close the question.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting your filters in Google Analytics?  With each account, you get 50 properties (different URLs).  Each property allows for 25 views.  These views allow you to set filters.  This allows you to pre-filter the data before it ever hits Power BI.